# How to display a dynamic URL in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication, conditional-statements

When I try to use this code I get a warning:

> Warning: printf(): Too few arguments

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
{
    printf( '<div class="someClass"><a href="https://domain.example/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.example%2FsomePage%2F%20">Login</a></div>', 
        wp_login_url( get_permalink() ),
        __( 'Login' )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf()` [outputs a formatted string](http://php.net/printf), so any time it encounters a `%` character followed by one or more of the elements listed [in the format section of the `sprintf()` man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters), you will need to provide this value as one of the parameters passed to this function in order of appearance in the string (unless argument swapping is used).

For example, in the string you have, you are using `%F`, which is the URL-encoded version of `/`. However `printf()` expects you to provide a floating point number to substitute the `%F` when outputting to the page.

Since you're not actually substituting any values in your string, just `echo` it instead of doing `printf()`:

```
echo '<div class="someClass"><a href="https://domain.example/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.example%2FsomePage%2F%20">Login</a></div>';
```

Or if you want to use `printf()` to be substituted into your string, I'm assuming this would be what you want:

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
{
    printf( '<div class="someClass"><a href="https://domain.example/login/?redirect_to=%s">%s</a></div>', 
        wp_login_url( get_permalink() ),
        __( 'Login' )
    );
}
```